# laravel validation check field equal something

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

how to check a field is exactly equal to a string or number
I want to check a field named `course_id` is equal a field of database `id` in `course` database. now I want to check if `course_id` is equal to `id`.

Comment: For details go ahead in documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate it by using the [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists) validation rule:

```
$validationRules = ['course_id' => 'exists:course,id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

create rule as below and use validator on input

```
$rules = array(
        'id'    => 'exists:your_table_name'
    );
```

for more help
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists